# NSDate comparison issues

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsdate

I just can't figure out what's going on here... Essentially, my code saves an object (to server) and logs the time in NSUserDefaults. The next time a user tries to save an object, I check to see if the date is in-between the stored time, and the stored time plus 2 hours. So basically, I want to prevent the user from saving an additional object within 2 hours of the other. I have the code written and finished... Here's the catch, it works 100% of the time on my end (Central Standard Time), but I have a beta tester in California (Pacific Time) that has issues with it. The times being recorded are correct, but the 2 hour windows are off, and often don't get overwritten... There's a few other places in the app where times can be updated, but the code is essentially, the exact same.

Here's the code in the "save object method":

```
    //Combine date and time
    NSCalendar *gregorianCalendar = [[NSCalendar alloc] initWithCalendarIdentifier:NSGregorianCalendar];
    NSDateComponents *components1 = [gregorianCalendar components:NSYearCalendarUnit | NSMonthCalendarUnit | NSDayCalendarUnit fromDate:self.pickedDate];
    NSDateComponents *components2 = [gregorianCalendar components:NSHourCalendarUnit | NSMinuteCalendarUnit | NSSecondCalendarUnit fromDate:self.pickedTime];
    NSDateComponents *components3 = [[NSDateComponents alloc] init];
    [components3 setYear:components1.year];
    [components3 setMonth:components1.month];
    [components3 setDay:components1.day];
    [components3 setHour:components2.hour];
    [components3 setMinute:components2.minute];
    [components3 setSecond:components2.second];

    //Generate a new NSDate from components3.
    NSDate *combinedDate = [gregorianCalendar dateFromComponents:components3];

    //Create "plus 2 hour" date
    NSUserDefaults *defaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
    NSDate *time = [defaults objectForKey:@"lastObject_time"];
    NSTimeInterval twoHours = 2 * 3600;
    NSDate *plusTwoHours = [time dateByAddingTimeInterval:twoHours];

    if (time) {
        //There is a stored time
        if (![self date:combinedDate isBetweenDate:time andDate:plusTwoHours]) {
            //After 2 hours, allow save. After save, check if it's the LATEST date, compared to what we have stored
            if ([combinedDate compare:[defaults objectForKey:@"lastObject_time"]] == NSOrderedDescending) {
                    //Save as most recent time
                    [defaults setObject:combinedDate forKey:@"lastObject_time"];
                    [defaults synchronize];
                }
        } else {
            //Before 2 hours, prevent save

        }
    } else {
        //No stored time, allow save

    }
```

Here's my `isBetweenDate` method

```
-(BOOL)date:(NSDate*)date isBetweenDate:(NSDate*)beginDate andDate:(NSDate*)endDate {
    if ([date compare:beginDate] == NSOrderedAscending)
        return NO;

    if ([date compare:endDate] == NSOrderedDescending)
        return NO;

    return YES;
}
```

Like I said, the times are stored according to their timezone, and I'm not thinking it's a timezone issue. My beta tester has had a few occasions of saving at 7 AM (stored time is 7 AM, blocked until 9 AM), then saves at 12 PM (which is allowed), but then the range doesn't update to 12-2 PM, and is stuck at 7-9 AM), and then they're allowed to save again at 12:01 PM Could there be a reason why it wouldn't work across timezones? Does anyone see anything that jumps out at them? Had similar experiences? Or is there an overall better way to do this?

Comment: When you deal with NSDate object if you do not change specifically the Timezone in a formatter you always work with Greenwich time zone. Are you sure that you don't change dates while formatting them from/for your server? Just anothr tips I would recommend to use Unix timestamp.

Comment: @Andrea I modify the timezone before saving them to the server. The actual day is important to my app, not just the time. Using Greenwich time would make the date in some cases wrong. All of the logged times are correct, even when I put my device in Los Angeles time and even something like London time. Maybe someone has a better, more reliable solution to this!

Comment: Create on your server a new service that gives you the time and create a delta between your date and server date, but in my experience changing the timezone often leads to problems

Comment: @Andrea thank you for your insight, I may begin to use unix...